# How to avoid a background animation to go back to it's initial point when taking off the cursor from there?

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

When hovered, this div's background image starts an animation. But when you take the cursor off, it goes back to it's initial point. How can I make it stays in the point it stopped when unhovered?

```css
div {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:indigo;
  background-image:url('https://abrilexame.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/aurora_borealis_i.jpg?quality=70&strip=info')
}

div:hover {
  -webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 5s ease 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation: backgroundScroll 5s ease 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes backgroundScroll {
    from {background-position: 0 0;}
    to {background-position:0px -180px ;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
    from {background-position: 0 0;}
    to {background-position:0px -180px ;}
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: You cannot, since CSS is a declerative language and does not retain states. You would need to use Javascript.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do it with JavaScript? I'm more familiar to JQuery, but if the solution is too complicated, I let it go

Comment: You would need to implement the animation with Javascript and implement Mouse-In and Mouse-Out events to trigger and stop it. I am not sure if jQuery's `.animate()` function is interruptable and resumable, you need to research that. Figuring out the best Concept would be a bit much right now.

Comment: @user3154108 Not really.... See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the animation on the base state, and play-state paused.

On hover, set it to running

```css
div {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:indigo;
  background-image:url('https://abrilexame.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/aurora_borealis_i.jpg?quality=70&strip=info');
  animation: backgroundScroll 5s ease 1;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div:hover {
  -webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 5s ease 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running;
}


@keyframes backgroundScroll {
    from {background-position: 0 0;}
    to {background-position:0px -180px ;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
    from {background-position: 0 0;}
    to {background-position:0px -180px ;}
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```